# Git branch inaccessible

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

**Edit**

Also, because the branches have the same name, how can I delete the current one I am on (the wrong one)?  If I checkout master than I won't know which branch is correct.

**Edit Edit**

I have run

`git branch --verbose`

```
master             99b97d2 prep test
migrate_to_rpsec   d91fd47 start model tests
* migrate_to_rspec   99b97d2 prep test
```

How can I delete/switch by upstream number?  I want the 2nd item on the list.

I created a separate branch named `migrate_to_rspec`.  I worked and committed to that branch

`git add .`

`git commit -m 'finish model tests'`

`git branch`

- master
- migrate_to_rspec

Then I moved to master

`git checkout master`

Then I tried to merge from the last branch

`git merge migrate_to_rspec`

And got 
    merge: migrate_to_rspec - not something we can merge

So I checked my branch again

`git branch`

- master
- migrate_to_rspec

And couldn't get back to the other branch

`git checkout migrate_to_rspec`

And got:
    error: pathspec 'migrate_to_rspec' did not match any file(s) known to git.

So then I ran (stupidly)
`git checkout -b migrate_to_rspec`

So now I have:

- master
- migrate_to_rpsec
- migrate_to_rspec

How can I got back to the original branch?  And how is there two of them with the same name but one I can't access and one I can?

Answer (score 1):

The low-level command that will show you the full spelling of everything is

```
git for-each-ref
```

and you can tell git to delete whichever ref looks wrong with

```
git update-ref -d $thatfullspelling
```

. . .

but in this case, I just noticed the problem:

```
migrate_to_rpsec
migrate_to_rspec
```

. . .

Comment: What I ended up doing because they did have the exact same name which I didn't think was possible was downloading a gui for it and managed to switch the branch in the gui and it updated on the command line.  Weird but it worked.